# DrRacket. Keybinding to duplicate selected lines

Tags: racket

How can I create a keybinding in Dr Racket to duplicate selected lines?

```
#lang s-exp framework/keybinding-lang
(keybinding "m:d" (λ (editor evt) ...))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this solution:

```
#lang s-exp framework/keybinding-lang
(keybinding
 "m:d"              ; Duplicate lines
 (λ (editor evt)
   (define pos1  (send editor get-start-position))
   (define pos2  (send editor get-end-position))
   (define line1 (send editor position-line pos1))
   (define line2 (send editor position-line pos2))

   (define text-begin (send editor line-start-position line1))
   (define text-end   (send editor line-end-position line2))

   (define selected-lines (send editor get-text text-begin text-end))

   (send editor insert (format "\n~a" selected-lines) text-end)
   (send editor set-position pos1 pos2)))
```

Add the file to DrRacket:
`Edit > Keybindings > Add User-defined Keybindings..` ;
Then restart the program.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that will duplicate the selected text at a point immediately after the end of the selection (So if an entire line(s) is selected, it'll be duplicated):

```lisp
#lang s-exp framework/keybinding-lang

(keybinding "m:d"
            (lambda (editor evt)
              (let* ([text-begin (send editor get-start-position)]
                     [text-end (send editor get-end-position)]
                     [selected-text (send editor get-text text-begin text-end)])
                (send editor insert selected-text text-end))))
```

Pretty simple; it just gets the positions of the current selection, gets the text in that range, and then inserts that text.